# error in create table from join in Mysql

Tags: mysql, left-join, create-table

I have 2 tables `A` and `B` which I want to join using a column `id` and create a third table `C` from that.
I performed this query:

```
create table C select * from ( A left join B using (id))T;
```

But it is giving error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T' at line 1
```

I don't know why the error is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the following

- parenthesis
- `FROM` before `SELECT`
- and the `ALIAS`

also

Tip, When creating a table with `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`, make sure to alias any function calls or expressions in the query. If you do not, the CREATE statement might fail or result in undesirable column names.

query,

```
CREATE TABLE C 
SELECT  * 
FROM    A 
        LEFT JOIN B USING (id)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8c51/1)
- [CREATE TABLE...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html)

Answer (score 1):

remove the round brackets and alias and it will be fine (at least for syntax)

```
create table C 
select * from  A left join B using (id);
```